# Improper support for character codes in code and pre blocks

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, design, pre

While editing [this response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/11697#11697), I found a bug in the character escaping code.  It is currently possible to write an & using `&amp;`, but there is no way to specify characters using the numerical code in a code block, which is what the OP at the linked answer wanted.  E.g.:

```
&amp;nbsp;
&nbsp&#59;
```

These should both display the same thing (the code `&nbsp;`) but neither of them displays correctly.  However, `&amp;nbsp;` and `&nbsp&#59;` do both work when not in a code block.  This is the same code as above, but in a `<pre>` block (shows that it doesn't work in inline code either):

```
& 
 ;
```

(Should appear the same as the first block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specific to code blocks, and a side effect of Google Prettify client-side JavaScript syntax highlighting.

Disable JavaScript and you'll find this works..

update: appears fixed with the latest prettify.js we've deployed.

Comment: Yeah, but disable Javascript and you straight away lose voting, comments, flagging, and myriad other important parts of the site as well!

Comment: regardless, it's an issue with `prettify.js` and not us

Answer (score 2):

For those without a high enough arbitrary number. Text indented four spaces:

```
=>&nbsp;<=
=>`&nbsp;`<=
=>`&nbsp;;`<=
=>&amp;nbsp;<=
=>&#38;nbsp;<=
=>&n&#98;sp;<=
=>&nbsp&#59;<=
```

Looks like none of these work.

Compare with `<pre>` block.

```
 
` `
` ;`
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
 ;
```

Comment: Alrighty then, `PRE` blocking it is.